# Looping through elements of a simple XML file with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm reading in a simple XML file:

```
<table>
    <title>List Title</title>
    <row rank="1" team_id="3" teamname="Name 1" score="205"/>
    <row rank="2" team_id="5" teamname="Name 2" score="100"/>
    <row rank="3" team_id="4" teamname="Name 3" score="77"/>
    <break/>
</table>
```

I need to populate the html with a table of team names and scores:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
            url: "http://theurl.com",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            contentType: 'text/xml', 

            success: function(data) {

                $(data).find('row').each(function() {  

                    var teamName = $(this).find('teamname').text();

                    console.log(teamName);
                });         

            }
        });

    });
```

What am I doing wrong? I do not see the team names in the console (although it does show a "3". What is the best way to get the team names and scores into an html table?

Comment: is this a cross domain request?

Answer (score 0):

When you parse the XML data with jQuery, a set of the elements within the root are returned. Use `.filter()` to grab the rows that are already in the set instead:

```
$(data).filter('row').each(function() {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

var teamName = $(this).attr("teamname");